# A new series for $\sqrt3/\pi$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, combinatorial-identities, ramanujan

Recently, I conjectured the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(66k^2+37k+4)\binom{2k}k\binom{3k}k\binom{4k}{2k}}{(2k+1)729^k}=\frac{27\sqrt3}{2\pi}.\tag{1}$$
This can be easily checked numerically via Mathematica or Maple as the series converges fast with the converging rate $16/27$. Note that $(1)$ is *not* of the Ramanujan type.

In the spirit of my paper "Series with summands involving harmonic numbers" available from http://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07238, motivated by $(1)$ I also conjecture that
\begin{align}&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k\binom{3k}k\binom{4k}{2k}}{(2k+1)729^k}\left((66k^2+37k+4)(2H_{4k}-H_{2k}-3H_k)+60k+26\right)
\\&\qquad=\frac{81\sqrt3\,\log3}{2\pi}\tag{2}\end{align}
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k\binom{3k}k\binom{4k}{2k}}{(2k+1)729^k}\left((66k^2+37k+4)(3H_{3k}-2H_{2k}+3H_k)-\frac{108k^2+92k+23}{2k+1}\right)
=0$$
where $H_n$ denotes the harmonic number $\sum_{0<j\le n}1/j$.

**QUESTION.** Is the identity $(1)$ new? If not, can one provide a reference? If it is new, how to prove the above three identities?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Is this identity part of some parametrized family of identities in one or more variables? You can try to use the Wilf Zeilberger method to verify the family which could be useful and give you the proof you are looking for.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilf-ZeilbergerPair.html I will add a warning in my limited knowledge of this the tool is often for sums that go up to a finite bound $n$ but it appears at the bottom of the wolfram page there are sums to infinity so this might still have utility